# Unity Tilemap RandomBrush with orientation and probabilities and fixes

Tags: c#, random, unity3d

Unity3D.com recently released a 2-D Tilemap system.

It comes with a really basic RandomBrush for painting a random tile from a list of tiles.

But the tiles were not being saved between preview and placement. And it was missing some features of a tile map brush as defined by the base class: rotate & flip & flood fill & box fill.

I aslo added probabilities and random flip/rotate.

[image]

[Repository here](https://github.com/rakkarage/TestRandomBrush).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;
namespace UnityEditor
{
    [CreateAssetMenu, CustomGridBrush(false, true, false, "Test Random Brush")]
    public class TestRandomBrush : GridBrush
    {
        [Flags]
        public enum Orientation
        {
            None = 0,
            FlipX = 1,
            FlipY = (1 << 1),
            Rot90 = (1 << 2),
        }
        public Orientation orientation = Orientation.None;
        private bool RandomBool => UnityEngine.Random.value > .5f;
        private bool FlipX => (orientation & Orientation.FlipX) == Orientation.FlipX ? RandomBool : false;
        private bool FlipY => (orientation & Orientation.FlipY) == Orientation.FlipY ? RandomBool : false;
        private bool Rot90 => (orientation & Orientation.Rot90) == Orientation.Rot90 ? RandomBool : false;
        private static Quaternion rotateClockwise = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -90f);
        private static Quaternion rotateCounter = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90f);
        private Matrix4x4 RandomMatrix => Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero,
            Rot90 ? rotateClockwise : Quaternion.identity, new Vector3(FlipX ? -1f : 1f, FlipY ? -1f : 1f, 1f));
        public TileBase[] randomTiles;
        public int[] probabilities;
        private TileBase RandomTile
        {
            get
            {
                if (probabilities?.Length == randomTiles.Length)
                {
                    var total = 0f;
                    var roll = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, probabilities.Sum());
                    for (var i = 0; i < probabilities.Length; i++)
                    {
                        total += probabilities[i];
                        if (roll < total)
                            return randomTiles[i];
                    }
                    return null;
                }
                else
                    return randomTiles[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, randomTiles.Length)];
            }
        }
        private Vector3Int? lastPosition;
        private Dictionary<Vector3Int, Tuple<TileBase, Matrix4x4>> cache = new Dictionary<Vector3Int, Tuple<TileBase, Matrix4x4>>();
        public Tuple<TileBase, Matrix4x4> this[Vector3Int key]
        {
            get
            {
                if (!cache.ContainsKey(key))
                    this[key] = new Tuple<TileBase, Matrix4x4>(RandomTile, RandomMatrix);
                return cache[key];
            }
            set
            {
                cache[key] = value;
                lastPosition = key;
            }
        }
        public void CacheClear(Vector3Int position)
        {
            if (position != lastPosition)
                cache.Clear();
        }
        public void CacheRemove(Vector3Int position) => cache.Remove(position);
        private FlipAxis? flipAxis;
        private RotationDirection? rotationDirection;
        public void CacheUpdate()
        {
            if (flipAxis.HasValue || rotationDirection.HasValue)
            {
                foreach (var i in cache.ToList())
                {
                    var m = i.Value.Item2;
                    var p = m.GetColumn(3);
                    var r = Quaternion.LookRotation(m.GetColumn(2), m.GetColumn(1));
                    var s = new Vector3(m.GetColumn(0).magnitude, m.GetColumn(1).magnitude, m.GetColumn(2).magnitude);
                    if (flipAxis.HasValue)
                        s = new Vector3(flipAxis.Value == FlipAxis.X ? s.x * -1f : s.x,
                            flipAxis.Value == FlipAxis.Y ? s.y * -1f : s.y, s.z);
                    if (rotationDirection.HasValue)
                        r *= rotationDirection.Value == RotationDirection.Clockwise ? rotateClockwise : rotateCounter;
                    m.SetTRS(p, r, s);
                    cache[i.Key] = new Tuple<TileBase, Matrix4x4>(i.Value.Item1, m);
                }
                flipAxis = null;
                rotationDirection = null;
            }
        }
        public BoundsInt Bounds(Vector3Int position)
        {
            var min = position - pivot;
            var max = min + size;
            return new BoundsInt(min, max - min);
        }
        public override void Flip(FlipAxis flip, GridLayout.CellLayout layout)
        {
            flipAxis = flip;
            base.Flip(flip, layout);
        }
        public override void Rotate(RotationDirection direction, GridLayout.CellLayout layout)
        {
            rotationDirection = direction;
            base.Rotate(direction, layout);
        }
        public override void Select(GridLayout gridLayout, GameObject brushTarget, BoundsInt position)
        {
            var map = brushTarget?.GetComponent<Tilemap>();
            if (!map)
                return;
            foreach (var i in position.allPositionsWithin)
            {
                var tile = map.GetTile(i);
                this[i] = new Tuple<TileBase, Matrix4x4>(tile, map.GetTransformMatrix(i));
            }
        }
        public override void Move(GridLayout gridLayout, GameObject brushTarget, BoundsInt from, BoundsInt to)
        {
            Vector3Int offset = to.min - from.min;
            foreach (var i in cache.ToList())
            {
                cache[i.Key] = null;
                cache[i.Key + offset] = i.Value;
            }
            base.Move(gridLayout, brushTarget, from, to);
        }
        public override void Paint(GridLayout gridLayout, GameObject brushTarget, Vector3Int position)
        {
            if (randomTiles?.Length > 0)
                Common(gridLayout, brushTarget, position);
        }
        public override void BoxFill(GridLayout gridLayout, GameObject brushTarget, BoundsInt position)
        {
            if (randomTiles?.Length > 0)
                foreach (var i in position.allPositionsWithin)
                    Common(gridLayout, brushTarget, i);
        }
        public override void FloodFill(GridLayout gridLayout, GameObject brushTarget, Vector3Int position)
        {
            if (randomTiles?.Length > 0)
            {
                var map = brushTarget?.GetComponent<Tilemap>();
                if (!map)
                    return;
                FloodFill(map, gridLayout, brushTarget, position);
            }
        }
        private void FloodFill(Tilemap map, GridLayout gridLayout, GameObject brushTarget, Vector3Int position)
        {
            var exist = map.GetTile(position);
            var points = new Stack<Vector3Int>();
            var used = new List<Vector3Int>();
            points.Push(position);
            while (points.Count > 0)
            {
                var p = points.Pop();
                used.Add(p);
                Common(map, gridLayout, brushTarget, p);
                for (var y = p.y - 1; y <= p.y + 1; y++)
                {
                    for (var x = p.x - 1; x <= p.x + 1; x++)
                    {
                        var test = new Vector3Int(x, y, p.z);
                        if ((test.y != p.y || test.x != p.x) && map.cellBounds.Contains(test) &&
                            (exist ? map.GetTile(test) : !map.GetTile(test)) && !used.Contains(test))
                            points.Push(test);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void Common(GridLayout gridLayout, GameObject brushTarget, Vector3Int position)
        {
            var map = brushTarget?.GetComponent<Tilemap>();
            if (!map)
                return;
            foreach (var i in Bounds(position).allPositionsWithin)
                Common(map, gridLayout, brushTarget, i);
        }
        private void Common(Tilemap map, GridLayout gridLayout, GameObject brushTarget, Vector3Int position)
        {
            var c = this[position];
            map.SetTile(position, c.Item1);
            map.SetTransformMatrix(position, c.Item2);
        }
    }
    [CustomEditor(typeof(TestRandomBrush))]
    public class TestRandomBrushEditor : GridBrushEditor
    {
        private TestRandomBrush RandomBrush => target as TestRandomBrush;
        private GameObject lastBrush;
        public override void PaintPreview(GridLayout gridLayout, GameObject brushTarget, Vector3Int position)
        {
            var brush = RandomBrush;
            brush.CacheClear(position);
            if (brush.randomTiles?.Length > 0)
                Common(gridLayout, brushTarget, position);
        }
        public override void BoxFillPreview(GridLayout gridLayout, GameObject brushTarget, BoundsInt position)
        {
            var map = brushTarget?.GetComponent<Tilemap>();
            if (!map)
                return;
            var brush = RandomBrush;
            foreach (var i in position.allPositionsWithin)
                if (map.GetTile(i) != null && map.GetEditorPreviewTile(i) != null)
                    brush.CacheRemove(i);
            if (brush.randomTiles?.Length > 0)
                foreach (var i in position.allPositionsWithin)
                    Common(gridLayout, brushTarget, i);
        }
        public override void FloodFillPreview(GridLayout gridLayout, GameObject brushTarget, Vector3Int position)
        {
            var brush = RandomBrush;
            brush.CacheClear(position);
            if (brush.randomTiles?.Length > 0)
            {
                var map = brushTarget?.GetComponent<Tilemap>();
                if (!map)
                    return;
                FloodFill(map, gridLayout, brushTarget, position);
            }
        }
        private void FloodFill(Tilemap map, GridLayout gridLayout, GameObject brushTarget, Vector3Int position)
        {
            var exist = map.GetTile(position);
            var points = new Stack<Vector3Int>();
            var used = new List<Vector3Int>();
            var bounds = map.cellBounds;
            var size = new Vector2Int((int)map.cellSize.x, (int)map.cellSize.y);
            points.Push(position);
            while (points.Count > 0)
            {
                var p = points.Pop();
                used.Add(p);
                if (!bounds.Contains(p))
                    bounds.SetMinMax(new Vector3Int(Math.Min(bounds.xMin, p.x), Math.Min(bounds.yMin, p.y), 0),
                        new Vector3Int(Math.Max(bounds.xMax, p.x) + size.x, Math.Max(bounds.yMax, p.y) + size.y, 1));
                Common(map, gridLayout, brushTarget, p);
                for (var y = p.y - 1; y <= p.y + 1; y++)
                {
                    for (var x = p.x - 1; x <= p.x + 1; x++)
                    {
                        var test = new Vector3Int(x, y, p.z);
                        if ((test.y != p.y || test.x != p.x) && bounds.Contains(test) &&
                            (exist ? map.GetTile(test) : !map.GetTile(test)) && !used.Contains(test))
                            points.Push(test);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void Common(GridLayout gridLayout, GameObject brushTarget, Vector3Int position)
        {
            var map = brushTarget?.GetComponent<Tilemap>();
            if (!map)
                return;
            foreach (var i in RandomBrush.Bounds(position).allPositionsWithin)
                Common(map, gridLayout, brushTarget, i);
        }
        private void Common(Tilemap map, GridLayout gridLayout, GameObject brushTarget, Vector3Int position)
        {
            var c = RandomBrush[position];
            map.SetEditorPreviewTile(position, c.Item1);
            map.SetEditorPreviewTransformMatrix(position, c.Item2);
            lastBrush = brushTarget;
        }
        public override void ClearPreview()
        {
            if (lastBrush != null)
            {
                RandomBrush.CacheUpdate();
                var map = lastBrush.GetComponent<Tilemap>();
                if (!map)
                    return;
                map.ClearAllEditorPreviewTiles();
                lastBrush = null;
            }
        }
        public override void OnPaintInspectorGUI() => GUI();
        public override void OnInspectorGUI() => GUI();
        private void GUI()
        {
            var brush = RandomBrush;
            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            brush.orientation = (TestRandomBrush.Orientation)EditorGUILayout.EnumFlagsField("Random Orientation", brush.orientation);
            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
                EditorUtility.SetDirty(brush);
            var so = serializedObject;
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(so.FindProperty(nameof(brush.randomTiles)), true);
            if (so.ApplyModifiedProperties())
                EditorUtility.SetDirty(brush);
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(so.FindProperty(nameof(brush.probabilities)), true);
            if (so.ApplyModifiedProperties())
                EditorUtility.SetDirty(brush);
        }
    }
}
```

Original code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

namespace UnityEditor
{
    [CustomGridBrush(false, true, false, "Random Brush")]
    public class RandomBrush : GridBrush 
    {
        public TileBase[] randomTiles;

        public override void Paint(GridLayout grid, GameObject brushTarget, Vector3Int position)
        {
            if (randomTiles != null && randomTiles.Length > 0)
            {
                if (brushTarget == null)
                    return;

                var tilemap = brushTarget.GetComponent<Tilemap>();
                if (tilemap == null)
                    return;

                Vector3Int min = position - pivot;
                BoundsInt bounds = new BoundsInt(min, size);
                foreach (Vector3Int location in bounds.allPositionsWithin)
                {
                    var randomTile = randomTiles[(int) (randomTiles.Length * UnityEngine.Random.value)];
                    tilemap.SetTile(location, randomTile);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                base.Paint(grid, brushTarget, position);
            }
        }

        [MenuItem("Assets/Create/Random Brush")]
        public static void CreateBrush()
        {
            string path = EditorUtility.SaveFilePanelInProject("Save Random Brush", "New Random Brush", "asset", "Save Random Brush", "Assets");

            if (path == "")
                return;

            AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<RandomBrush>(), path);
        }
    }

    [CustomEditor(typeof(RandomBrush))]
    public class RandomBrushEditor : GridBrushEditor
    {
        private RandomBrush randomBrush { get { return target as RandomBrush; } }
        private GameObject lastBrushTarget;

        public override void PaintPreview(GridLayout grid, GameObject brushTarget, Vector3Int position)
        {
            if (randomBrush.randomTiles != null && randomBrush.randomTiles.Length > 0)
            {
                base.PaintPreview(grid, null, position);

                if (brushTarget == null)
                    return;

                var tilemap = brushTarget.GetComponent<Tilemap>();
                if (tilemap == null)
                    return;

                Vector3Int min = position - randomBrush.pivot;
                BoundsInt bounds = new BoundsInt(min, randomBrush.size);
                foreach (Vector3Int location in bounds.allPositionsWithin)
                {
                    var randomTile = randomBrush.randomTiles[(int) (randomBrush.randomTiles.Length * UnityEngine.Random.value)];
                    tilemap.SetEditorPreviewTile(location, randomTile);
                }

                lastBrushTarget = brushTarget;
            }
            else
            {
                base.PaintPreview(grid, brushTarget, position);
            }
        }

        public override void ClearPreview()
        {
            if (lastBrushTarget != null)
            {
                var tilemap = lastBrushTarget.GetComponent<Tilemap>();
                if (tilemap == null)
                    return;

                tilemap.ClearAllEditorPreviewTiles();

                lastBrushTarget = null;
            }
            else
            {
                base.ClearPreview();
            }
        }

        public override void OnPaintInspectorGUI()
        {
            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            int count = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Number of Tiles", randomBrush.randomTiles != null ?   randomBrush.randomTiles.Length : 0);
            if (count < 0)
                count = 0;
            if (randomBrush.randomTiles == null || randomBrush.randomTiles.Length != count)
            {
                Array.Resize<TileBase>(ref randomBrush.randomTiles, count);
            }

            if (count == 0)
                return;

            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Place random tiles.");
            EditorGUILayout.Space();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                randomBrush.randomTiles[i] = (TileBase) EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Tile " + (i+1), randomBrush.randomTiles[i], typeof(TileBase), false, null);
            }       
            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
                EditorUtility.SetDirty(randomBrush);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i could remove the first else

Comment: I don't think a lot of people on codereview are familiar with Unity (the game engine, not the dependency injection framework), so you may want to provide a bit more context. What does a `GridBrush` do, for example? Also, what sort of feedback are you looking for?